# Convert some columns in Google sheet to rows for better presentation

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that gets all the info from a google sheet form - [Sheet1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CzJi7tH0dHx1NFPpLrwvr_v7pd7mIkNMXY5PA3a57T4/edit#gid=0)
Also image here

[image: Data Sheet1]

I am trying to process this data consolidating all the line item and format info from each booking and present in better readable format and pass it in Output Sheet mentioned in the next tab also the table image underneath

[image: Output sheet]

I will appreciate if someone can please help me with this.

I want to collate all the information from the line items and their formats mentioned as different columns in the Sheet1 to appear in a more presentable way.
The limiting column are Column E, H and K which say "any more lines?"

Comment: it will probably be quicker to do it by hand then learning to code and then doing it.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(Sheet1!A2:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,ifna(hstack(filter(Sheet1!A:B,Sheet1!A:A=c),wraprows(filter({Sheet1!C:D,Sheet1!F:G,Sheet1!I:J,Sheet1!L:M},Sheet1!A:A=c),2),filter(Sheet1!N:O,Sheet1!A:A=c)))))),
       filter(Σ,index(Σ,,3)<>""))
```

- ***remove the manual data** (comments+expected output in `Sheet1`) entered in row 18 & rows 25-32 for the formula to work as intended*
- *also the formula assumes the client names in Column_A are uniquely listed (no repetitions). let us know if that's not the scenario as it'd need a diff. formula variation*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=QUERY(
   IFNA(
     REDUCE({Sheet1!A1:D1,Sheet1!N1:O1},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)),
       LAMBDA(table,i,
          VSTACK(table,HSTACK(INDEX(Sheet1!A2:B,i),
                 VSTACK(INDEX({Sheet1!C2:D,Sheet1!N2:O},i),INDEX(Sheet1!F2:G,i),INDEX(Sheet1!I2:J,i))))))),
   "where Col3<>''")
```

[image]